# core data error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching on object 0

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data, crash

I'm creating a core data favorite feature. I have a favorite attribute with type boolean in recipe table. There are 2 views.

First view is for user to select favorite.
Second view display a list of favorites that is selected.

The feature works fine when i go to the  first view. However, the app crashed after i go to the second view and go back to first view again. I get the following error:

```
    2012-01-09 18:44:09.455 coredata[1354:12503] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  Can't do regex matching on object 0. with userInfo (null)
    2012-01-09 18:44:09.457 coredata[1354:12503] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching on object 0.'
```

My code for the method in first view that toggle the favorite attribute to 1 or 0:

```
    - (IBAction)favoriteButtonPressed:(id)sender {
```

```
 if (recipe.favorite == 0) {

 [favoriteButton setSelected:YES];
 favoriteButtonSelected = 1;
 [favoriteButtonImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     self.recipe.favorite = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1];

 }else {

 [favoriteButton setSelected:NO];
 favoriteButtonSelected = 0;
 [favoriteButtonImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     self.recipe.favorite = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:0];

 }
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = recipe.managedObjectContext;
    NSError *error;
 if (![context save:&error]) {
  NSLog(@"Tried to save favorite Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);abort();
     }
}
```

**Updated:**
Is it a problem that i did not update the database? I have searched around and found the following method, where should i include this into the code?

```
[context refreshObject:recipe mergeChanges:NO];
```

Can anyone help please? Thanks!

Comment: Did the traceback point anywhere near the code you posted??

Comment: I have placed breakpoints and it stopped at   NSManagedObjectContext *context = recipe.managedObjectContext;

Comment: Yes, but after the error occurred did you check the console for a traceback?

Comment: it only shows these:                                                Pending breakpoint 1 - ""RecipeDetailViewController.m":864" resolved
Pending breakpoint 2 - ""RecipeDetailViewController.m":860" resolved
Pending breakpoint 3 - ""RecipeDetailViewController.m":852" resolved

Answer (score 2):

Try to put `[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"root"];`

in the

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController{
...}
```

It solved me the problem. Hope it helps